# Disabling Vulnerability Scanning for GCP using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am using Azure Devops pipeline to create Artifact registry using service-connection and need to disable vulnerability scanning .

In the main.tf file after creating artifact registry I added null resource with the provisioner as below.

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
   command = "gcloud services disable containerscanning.googleapis.com --project=test --force"
   }
```

Artifact registry is created succesfully but while running null resource throwing error as

**Error running command 'gcloud services disable containerscanning.googleapis.com --project=test --force': exit status 1. Output: ERROR: (gcloud.services.disable) You do not currently have an active account selected.**

I found a workaround using null resource using with the command **gcloud auth activate-service-account**. My questions are

- Artifact registry is created with the provided service connection details and why it is asking for credentials inside null resource.
- Can we disable vulnerability scanning using terraform using without using null resource

*Any help is truly appreciated*

Answer (score 0):

Your local-exec gcloud command error is likely due to credential authentication issue. Though you created the artifact repository with proper credential, the call to disable containerscanning api is a separate REST call to the GCP API server which requires a new auth session or existing credential passed in. You can try the command with specific user account (if you are not running with [Application Default Credential configured](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc)):

```
gcloud services disable containerscanning.googleapis.com --account="user_xxx@gmail.com"
```

You might want to use Terraform to disable service.

```
resource "google_project_service" "project" {
  service = "containerscanning.googleapis.com"

  disable_dependent_services = true
  disable_on_destroy = true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried with default login but same eror. disable_dependent_services will this disable the service "container scanning.googleapis.com" or will it have any other dependencies. Meaning will AR be affected. Correct me if I am wrong, providing disable_on_destroy =true means after running terraform destroy the service container scanning.googleapis.com will still be in disabled state.

Comment: `disable_on_destroy=true` allows you to disable the containerscanning API when running `terraform destroy`. `disable_dependent_services` will disable other services that depends on containerscanning service. Otherwise you will get an error. So `disable_on_destry` disables the services, while `disable_dependent_services` does the safe guarding. Detail see here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_service.

Comment: how did you get the application default credential? and where did you run the terraform code? can you provide more code snippet of your terraform code. I just run the same `local-exec` on my laptops, works fine. 

-----

resource "terraform_data" "example1" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "gcloud services disable containerscanning.googleapis.com --project=test-project --force"
  }
}

Comment: I have used resource "google_project_service" "project" as you specified but vulnerability scanning is in enabled state. I am using Azure pipelines to deploy terraform code with task as 
````
- task: TerraformTaskV4@4
     inputs:
      provider: 'gcp'
      command: 'apply'
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(directorypath)/servicename'
      environmentServiceName: '$(service-connection)'
````

Comment: did you try update your Azure pipeline to destroy the resource instead of apply? `- task: TerraformTaskV4@4 inputs: provider: 'gcp' command: 'destroy' workingDirectory:...`

Comment: terraform state file contains the data which i applied through the terraform but my state file will not contain any data related to vulnerability scanning. May i know how running terraform destroy will help on this.

Comment: `disable_on_destroy` disable the service when the Terraform resource is destroyed. In this case, the terraform resource will be the `google_project_service`. So, you either comment out the resource from your terraform file then run `terraform apply`, or run `terraform destroy` which might not be feasible because of other resources provisioned by tf module.